# Multiply with overflow: Rust Runtime error

Tags: rust, types, runtime-error, unsigned-integer

In the Rust program, I'm trying to write I'm required to multiply 2 `u64`s and count the number of `1`s when the product is represented as binary.

```rust
// Intentionally left uninitialized
let some_u64: u64;
let another_u64: u64;
let product = some_u64 * another_u64;
```

This operation will result in this "data type" for the `product` variable - (I'm not sure exactly what it is).

```rust
<u64 as Mul<u64>>::Output
```

When compiling this, it doesn't return any errors. However, when running it, it returns the following error.

```rust
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', src/file.rs:67:23
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

With the `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable

```rust
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', src/magics.rs:67:23
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library/std/src/panicking.rs:575:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library/core/src/panicking.rs:65:14
   2: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library/core/src/panicking.rs:115:5
   3: rust_chess::magics::find_magics
             at ./src/file.rs:67:23
   4: rust_chess::magics::init
             at ./src/file.rs:10:13
   5: rust_chess::main
             at ./src/main.rs:11:5
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:251:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

What should I do in order to multiply 2 `u64`s and use the product without having runtime errors?

FYI, I've tried to cast it to `u128`, which unfortunately led to the same result.

**EDIT:** Here is a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b73883257ea46a657b0f9c1b01be393f) to see a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: See [`checked_mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u64.html#method.checked_mul) (stable) and [`widening_mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u64.html#method.widening_mul) (nightly).

Comment: [`<u64 as Mul<u64>>::Output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u64.html#associatedtype.Output-7) is `u64`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I've added a playground link that reproduces the exact same I was trying to describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `u64`s into `u128`s *before* multiplying them to avoid an overflow:

```
let some_num: u64 = 36670911850479872;
let another_num: u64 = 18049651735527936;

let product = u128::from(some_num) * u128::from(another_num);

println!("{} * {} = {}", some_num, another_num, product);
```

```
36670911850479872 * 18049651735527936 = 661897187725405976746072861704192
```

Comment: Some might argue, that this is only half the answer. As the question is not clear about the desired outcome. The (not written) second part could answer: "What do I have to do so rust ignores the overflow?"

Comment: @BitTickler I agree that the question could be more clear, but I took this as the desired result based on the premise that they want to multiply so they can count the bits, which would mean holding the complete result and not a modulo of it or something. Though `widening_mul` suggested by John Kugelman would also work for this purpose.